# Solution import failed with no status value on process and process activation items Dynamic crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I tried to import an unmanaged solution file. The import always failed and didn't give any error messages.

I sorted the Status column in the importing solution window, and found that all entities/forms/views/charts were fine. However, all items with type = process/process activation (customized) didn't have any value in "Date Time" and "Status" columns.

```css
<Data ss:Type="String" ss:Res="Customization.Sol_Status">Status</Data></Cell><Cell ss:StyleID="s137"><Data ss:Type="String">Failure</Data></Cell></Row><Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" parent="Solution"><Cell ss:StyleID="s176"><Data ss:Type="String" ss:Res="Customization.Sol_Message">Message</Data></Cell><Cell ss:StyleID="s137"><Data ss:Type="String">The import failed. For more information, see the related error messages.</Data></Cell></Row><Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" parent="Solution"><Cell ss:StyleID="s176"><Data ss:Type="String" ss:Res="Customization.Sol_Progress">Progress [%]</Data></Cell><Cell ss:StyleID="s137"><Data ss:Type="String">73.01</Data></Cell></Row><Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" parent="Solution"><Cell ss:StyleID="s176"><Data ss:Type="String" ss:Res="Customization.Sol_Duration">Duration [s]</Data></Cell><Cell ss:StyleID="s137"><Data ss:Type="String">95.2</Data></Cell></Row></Table>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Zni.jpg)

Comment: How do you know the import failed if there wasn't an error message?

Comment: During the solution import process, the green progress bar eventually rolled back, and the import solution window showed "the import of solution: xxx failed". No red-check mark in Status column, no error/message in Description & Detail columns.

Comment: @JamesWood I have also added a screenshot for your better understanding.

Comment: Have you downloaded the Excel error file?

Comment: yes i have downloaded the XML error log file.

Comment: What additional information did the XML error log have?  That should tell you what component it failed on and usually has enough information in the error message to help resolve the issue.  If you can post what the component and error message were, that would be very helpful.  Also, what version of CRM are you working with: online or on-prem?

Comment: I am using On-Prem version of CRM
I have edited my question with part of error log messages but there isn't enough information specified in the error log file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional info.  It seems that you are looking at the raw XML of the error log file, do you have Excel to open the file with?  When viewing the file in Excel, there are two sheets in the file, one is a summary and the other is all the details, the XML excerpt you added appears to be from the summary sheet.  If you can open it in Excel or dig through the XML to get the details that would be very helpful.

Comment: @AK3800 But I am not seeing any error code or error text for all the unprocessed statuses! There are many unprocessed components without any errors.

Comment: Correct, what you'll see is a processed status for any components that were successful up to the point of the failure, then the component with the failure and the error details, and then the remaining components that were not processed.  Once a component fails the transaction rolls back immediately so it won't attempt to finish the other components.  If you can't open the file in Excel, then you can still look at the raw XML and get the actual error message.

Comment: @user3396612, here is a snippet from one of my failed import log files:  `<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" type="Entity">
   ...
   <Cell ss:StyleID="s137" name="Status">
      <Data ss:Type="String">Failure</Data>
   </Cell>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="s137" name="ErrorCode">
      <Data ss:Type="String">0x80040203</Data>
   </Cell>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="s137" name="ErrorText">
      <Data ss:Type="String">Updating RecurringAppointmentMaster.subject.Length but it's not valid for update. Original value:500. New value:400.</Data>
   </Cell>
</Row>`

Comment: @AK3800 you must have seen the snippet from my failed imported log files.As my log files contains no more messages other than  "The import failed. For more information, see the related error messages".What should i do in this scenario?. I have clearly read all the log file and it contains nothing more than the error message that i posted above.

Comment: @user3396612 are you able to open the XML import log file in Excel, or post the complete file/link to it from here?  Without that unfortunately I don't have anything more to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of debugging CRM solution imports...

I find that your best bet is to [enable tracing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907490) on your CRM server. This can be done easily by using the [Diagnostics Tool for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011/2013/2015](https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/): Just press *Enable Trace* and run your solution import. It will take significantly longer to do an import while tracing, so you might want to wait with enabling tracing until your import has reached the approximate point where the progress bar starts moving backwards.

To view the logs in an easy way I suggest using [Trace Reader for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://crmtracereader.codeplex.com/). If you filter to view only error messages you should be much closer to figuring out why your solution import fails (since you will be able to see exactly which SQL statement is failing).

Answer (score 0):

If any workflows in the solution already exist in the target organisation make sure you've assigned ownership of those workflows to the user doing the import.